# Overlaying a polyshape to faceted maps in R with ggplot?

Tags: r, polygon, cartography, overlay, ggplot2

I have managed to create a faceted map from my data following the approach proposed here http://spatial.ly/2013/12/introduction-spatial-data-ggplot2/ 
with the following code:

```
ggplot(data = plot.data, aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = value, group = group)) + 
  geom_polygon() + coord_equal() + 
  facet_wrap(~variable,labeller = as_labeller(names), ncol=2)
```

Where

```
plot.data <- merge(bound.f, mdata.melt, by.x = "id", by.y = "uid")
```

and `bound.f` is the fortified spatial polyshape (with sub-national boundaries)
and `mdata.melt` is the data used in map, in the the long format.

And I get the following output:

[image: output map :In case you don't see, it is the African continent]

So far so good. Now I would like to add (overlay) the boundaries of the African countries (which I have a shapefile, same projection than bound) to both maps.

In other words, I want to add the shape, which boundaries should be black and the shape with no fill.

Does anyone have a hint on how I could code this or even has a smarter approach to get beautiful maps into my publication?

Answer (score 2):

So i finally made it ! with the following code

```
   map<- ggplot(data = plot.data, aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = value, group = group)) 
   + geom_polygon() + coord_equal() +
   facet_wrap(~variable,labeller = as_labeller(names))
```

then

```
map+geom_path(data=africa.f, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), lwd = 0.01,inherit.aes = F)
```

The trick was the inherit.aes = F which avoid calling on the previous layer

Comment: I have the same problem, but even after your solution, the overlayed layer is displayed on top of the previous map, instead of being below it. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to get a list of the state names and add them like this

```
library(XML)
library(ggplot2)
doc <- htmlParse(readLines("https://www.countries-ofthe-world.com/countries-of-africa.html"))
countries <- tolower(xpathSApply(doc, "/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li[not(@class)]", xmlValue))
ggplot() + borders(regions = countries)
```

Some names are still missing; you can add them to `countries` in the veins of `countries <- c(countries, "another state", "and another one")`. The country names must match the ones in `map(plot=F)$names` in order to be recognized.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support! as i had an existing shapefile for the boundaries i went a different way!