# What does "faceting" mean in a geo/map context?

Tags: layers, cartography, visualisation, display, terminology

I saw some folks talking about "faceting" in relation to a map data display, what does this mean in general terms? Examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One concept of 'faceting' is to display data in separated maps (known as panels), so to emphasize groups or subgroups of data.

For example, each panel can represent a timestamp (commonly used to represent historical climate data). Here is one example from New Zealand's [National Institute of Water and Atmospheric Research](https://www.niwa.co.nz/climate/daily-climate-maps).

[image]

First time I came across 'faceting' was with R package `ggplot2`. For instance, see [Overlaying a polyshape to faceted maps in R with ggplot?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188337/overlaying-a-polyshape-to-faceted-maps-in-r-with-ggplot) (more examples can be found in Google, [link](https://www.google.com.br/search?biw=1242&bih=525&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=-aWjW53lKIPswATroKSQBw&q=ggplot+facet+maps&oq=ggplot+facet+maps&gs_l=img.3...15863.16432.0.16662.5.5.0.0.0.0.190.369.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.img..3.1.188...0j0i30k1j0i8i30k1j0i24k1.0.Bx44qnlfcSc)).

Moreover, as pointed out by Steven Kay, another term for 'faceting' is [small multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_multiple) maps. Indeed, a quick [search](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=small+multiples+maps&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDlruYusrdAhWBEJAKHUHaAfAQ_AUIDigB&biw=1242&bih=525) in Google also returned many true positives for it.